# Why aren't votes on questions taken into tag score?

Tags: feature-request, tags, score

On Stack Overflow, the score next to the JS tag on my profile page helpfully shows the following (on mouse over):

> "Asked 14 non-wiki questions with a total score of 53. Answered 527 non-wiki questions with a total score of 628."

So the total score is 628 (answer UV - DV), but the total tag-usage, or whatever you call it is `541` (527+14). In other words: the number of non-wiki questions is added to the tag-usage total, but the up/down votes you got on questions aren't added to the total score.

Why aren't they?

If you put in the effort and write a great question, which in turn yields a good, helpful answer. There is an argument in saying you were, at least partly responsible for that answer, because you came up with the question.
Take, for example [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10381296/best-way-to-get-child-nodes). It's not a very complicated topic, nor is the answer very *"new"* per se, but even now, one year on, I occasionally get an upvote, and the question itself has been viewed for getting on 25k times.
My guess is that's because it provides an overview of the various ways of getting the child nodes in JS, the differences between these approaches and the pitfalls. Which is, if I'm not mistaken, what SO is about: providing a knowledge resource in a Q&A format.

Questions are, IMHO, as important as decent answers are... why not treat them similarly?

Comment: Maybe there should be badges like "javascript?" for asking questions, in symmetry to "javascrip" for answering them.

Comment: Voting works different on meta, shows agreement or disagreement with your request.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the tag score is representing your skill and knowledge in the specific area of the tag.

And on stackoverflow you show your skill by answering questions and getting upvotes for your answer (and therefore on the tags of the question).

The tag score is then an indicator for other users how good you know the specific technology.

If questions would be included in the tag score, then the tag score would have no meaning. 
Cause you could ask many (good) questions (that increase your tag score), but give no answers.

Comment: You have a point there. Answers are certainly the easiest/surest way of determining how knowledgeable someone is. But if you write a good question (showing what you've tried, explaining what the expected behaviour would be), doesn't that require some knowledge, too? Some users get their rep from asking questions. I see no bones in that, either...

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem of course (and it appropriately rewarded with rep), but its a different kind of knowledge

Comment: @RichardTingle: granted, it's a different kind of knowledge, but wouldn't it make more sense, then, to also _not_ include the questions in the total tag-usage count? Since it's a different use of the tags

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem yes maybe, but it shows your activity (asking and answering) in the tag and if you are only a "one hit wonder" (few bomb posts) or "tag stable" (many good posts)

Comment: @Jehof: Ok, I'm conviced... sorry for being a tad head-strong. Sometimes, I just _have_ to know why something is the way it is :)