# Why does the Tags section of the profile count questions asked, but not their score?

Tags: feature-request, tags, score

Note: [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187461/why-arent-votes-on-questions-taken-into-tag-score) addresses part of what I'm asking here, but not everything. I also want to know why the *number of questions* for a given tag is included if the score is not.

---

Also note: [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/153597/what-on-earth-creates-the-number-next-to-my-tag-score-in-my-profile) is not asking about the same thing either. It's referring to the inclusion of *community wiki* posts in the count.

---

In the tags tab of user profiles:

[image: tags tab]

We see the number of posts for any given tag:

[image: number of posts]

and the total score for *answers in that tag*:

[image: score for tag]

Why are points awarded for questions not included in the score while the number of questions is included in the count?

I think it would make more sense to either:

- include the question score in the tag total; or
- exclude the number of questions when calculating the number of posts for the tag

Comment: If anything I would vote to exclude the questions when calculating the number of posts, since I view this area more as a rough indicator of expertise in a tag (where in general providing answers suggest expertise while asking questions does not). That said I 100% agree with tohecz interpretation below and kind of like it the way it is.

Answer (score 3):

Total number of posts is good for knowing what is your field of interest. The total answer score shows how much an expert are you in that field. So that's why these two things differ.

For tag badges, only the answers count, so the score mentioned is the right for them, but the number is not.

*(I had found it confusing only for the first couple months, basically until I got the first tag badge, then I got used to it.)*