# Top tag in activity should count question score as well

Tags: feature-request, tags, profile-page, tag-score

In the new *activity* view on the profile page, it includes your top tag. As it stands, this is identical to the top tag later down on the page, meaning it only calculates answer score. This makes 100% sense in the tags view later, as it lets you quickly see how close you are to a tag badge (among other uses *;)*). (see [Why does the Tags section of the profile count questions asked, but not their score?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240677/why-does-the-tags-section-of-the-profile-count-questions-asked-but-not-their-sc))

Now, this is all well and good in the tag table, but i feel like your "top tag" should be whichever you have the highest *total* score in -- questions and answers.

A couple examples where this would make a difference:

On [my Worldbuilding.SE profile](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/users/2665/scimonster?tab=topactivity), it lists my top tag as [planets](/questions/tagged/planets). By an answer count, that's true -- i have a score of 4. But if we count questions, my top tag would be [culture](/questions/tagged/culture), with an answer score of 3 and a question score of 17, totaling 20.
On my [Judaism.SE profile](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/5151/scimonster?tab=topactivity) (not switched over yet), my top tag by answers is [purim-torah-in-jest](/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest) -- 104 answer score + 76 question score = 180 total score. However, [halacha](/questions/tagged/halacha) nets me 76 answer score + 309 question score = 385 total score -- 205 above my "top tag".

I think that only counting answers here can give a false representation of where people spend their time on the site, especially people who ask more than answer.