# Top Tags for Questions

Tags: feature-request, tags, profile-page

The main displayed stats for Tags have always been for Answers, with Questions demoted to only be mentioned in tooltips.

With the new prominence of the Top Tags in the new-style Profile page, perhaps it can now have a Questions view as well (i.e. without having to look at the tooltips, which are still there).

I note the related question about [changing the score displayed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/254568/147650). I'm just suggesting the existing Answers-based score as the default and a Questions view displaying the existing Questions-based score already displayed in the tooltip.