# Improve the 'top tags' section on profile

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, top-tags

On my profile, my `top tags` on EL&U are currently shown like this:

> [image]

But I find this misleading- sure, I may have 21 posts in the [etymology](/questions/tagged/etymology) tag, and a total answer-score of 115, but the current formatting is (kind of) confusing. Actually, as the tooltip shows, in that tag, I have 13 answers with an aggregate score of 115, and 8 questions with an aggregate score 47. The current setup completely ignores my asking-score, and in general sort of misrepresents the story for users who ask and answer within the same tag.

It also makes users who *ask* a lot of questions look bad- a user may have asked 21 questions in a tag and answered 1 question, but it'll still make it seem as though their score-per-answer is worse than it is.

I admit, these are sort of superficial issues, but they still sort of annoy me. I think it would be nice if we had something more reflective of the actual breakdown, plus an opportunity to get more information about the user's contribution by tag.

So, I suggest that we:

- get rid of the %-posts metric, because nobody cares about that (at least, I don't)
- allow users to sort within `all`, `asking`, and `answering`; this would also make it parallel with the top posts section, which can already be split by post-type

Here's a (bad) mock-up:

> [image]

(My example excludes community-wiki posts and I forgot to add the 'View all tags' link, but those can probably be added in somehow)

[feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request): Make the top tags metric more interactive and reflective of a user's contribution

Comment: Regarding why tag score only counts answer votes: [Why aren't votes on questions taken into tag score?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187461/241919)